# SQL: CASE ... WHEN IN ..., to return which OR holds

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

```
SELECT *, someSpecialProperty 
FROM table 
WHERE x = @mail 
   OR y IN (SELECT y FROM someTable WHERE m = @mail) 
   OR z IN (SELECT z FROM otherTable WHERE otherM = @mail)
```

`someSpecialProperty` should be

- `1` if the first of the three conditions holds
- `2` if the second of the three conditions hold, but not the first
- `3` if the third of three conditions hold, but neither the second or the first

So I tried

```
CASE x WHEN @mail THEN 1 ELSE 
CASE y WHEN IN(SELECT y FROM someTable WHERE m=@mail) THEN 2 ELSE
CASE z WHEN IN(SELECT z FROM otherTable WHERE otherM=@mail) THEN 3 ELSE 0 END
AS someSpecialProperty
```

But

> "the syntax is incorrect near `IN`".

How could I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN x = @mail THEN 1
        WHEN y IN (SELECT y FROM someTable WHERE m = @mail) THEN 2
        WHEN z IN (SELECT z FROM otherTable WHERE otherM = @mail) THEN 3 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS newField
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use EXISTS instead of Y IN IN (SELECT ...) :

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN x = @email THEN 1
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT y FROM someTable AS S WHERE S.m=@mail AND S.y = T.y ) THEN 2 /* y here should be the column from outer table T*/
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT z FROM otherTable AS O WHERE O.otherM=@mail AND O.z = T.z) THEN 3 /* z here should be the column from outer table T */
    ELSE 0
END
FROM table T
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: *y* here will never be the column from the outer table, not unless you prefix it with an alias from the outer table

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to do this by putting the conditions in the `select` and using a subquery for the `where`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (case when x = @mail then 1 
                   when y IN (SELECT y FROM someTable WHERE m = @mail) then 2
                   when z IN (SELECT z FROM otherTable WHERE otherM = @mail) then 3
              end) as someSpecialProperty 
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE someSpecialProperty IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN x = @mail THEN 1 
       WHEN exists 
         (SELECT null FROM someTable  t1 WHERE t1.m=@mail and x.y = t1.y)
       THEN 2
       WHEN exists 
         (SELECT null FROM otherTable t2 WHERE t2.otherM=@mail and x.z = t2.z) 
       THEN 3
  END AS someSpecialProperty -- this value will never be other values than 1,2 or 3
FROM <table> x
WHERE 
  x = @mail 
  OR exists (SELECT null FROM someTable t1  WHERE t1.m = @mail and x.y = t1.y) 
  OR exists (SELECT null FROM otherTable t2 WHERE t2.otherM = @mail and x.z = t1.z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an apply operator conveniently allows referring to that case expression via its column alias in the where clause.

```
SELECT
      t.*, CA.someSpecialProperty
FROM table1 t
CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                  CASE
                        WHEN x = @mail THEN 1
                        WHEN y IN (
                                    SELECT y FROM someTable WHERE m = @mail
                                  ) THEN 2
                        WHEN z IN (
                                    SELECT z FROM otherTable WHERE otherM = @mail
                                  ) THEN 3 
                  END
            ) CA (someSpecialProperty)
WHERE CA.someSpecialProperty IS NOT NULL
;
```

Answer (score -1):

> "The CASE statement evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops
>   with the first condition whose condition is satisfied. "

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
CASE WHEN x = @mail THEN 1
     WHEN y IN(SELECT y FROM someTable WHERE m=@mail) THEN 2
     WHEN z IN(SELECT z FROM otherTable WHERE otherM=@mail) THEN 3 
     ELSE 0 END
AS someSpecialProperty
```

Comment: you are not checking for x and z values in the subtables. The 2 first ELSE is invalid syntax

Comment: @t-clausen.dk dangers of copying and pasting an OPs example... guilty as charged.

Comment: you are still not checking for y and z values in the sub queries

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I've simply reproduced the OPS pseudo query. Given the Case clause satisfies the OPS conditions,  I'm not sure the clarity of the original question is such that we can assert that the y query does not contain any x rows and likewise the z query does not contain any x or y rows. Perhaps if the OP clarified

Comment: in the original query y and z was compared. You are not comparing them